# Make dns-sd exit after listing service

Tags: macos, airplay, bonjour

Is there a way to make dns-sd just list a service and then exit? I am using

```
dns-sd -L "abcdef123@MySpeaker" _raop._tcp. local.
```

To list an AirPlay device's details but it keeps running once that is done.

Context: I have an AirPlay speaker that is slow to show up in the AirPlay speaker list on devices. The AppleTV shows up instantly so I was hoping to get some stats on when the speaker is slow to show up vs. not; as a way to understand what the issue might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s designed to not exit. We have to track the process and send it an exit / kill signal. Apple even calls this out in the manual page but they do publish a C interface in [mDNSResponder/dns_sd.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/mDNSResponder/mDNSResponder-878.70.2/mDNSShared/dns_sd.h.auto.html)

> For example, calls like "browse" never
> complete; the action of performing a "browse" sets in motion machinery to
> notify the client whenever instances of that service type appear or
> disappear from the network. These notifications continue to be delivered
> indefinitely, for minutes, hours, or even days, as services come and go,
> until the client explicitly terminates the call.

The best I can do for scripting is use `expect` to fork the process with a timeout or just use something brute force like backgrounding the command so I can sleep and kill it and copy the results to the pasteboard.

```shell
dns-sd -B _home-sharing &
sleep 5 && kill %1
```

If you have another background process as `%1`, this will kill the wrong process.

In practice, I've never had to wait more than 30 seconds for a good browse or listen but not all networks are the same size.

Answer (score 3):

use `-t` flag to set exitTime.

```
if (argc > 2 && !strcmp(argv[1], "-t))
{
    exitTimeout = atoi(argv[2]);
    argc -= 2;
    argv +=2:
}
```

you must set `-t` flag as the first `argv`.
example: `dns-sd -t 1 -Q 'your-Macbook-Pro.local.'`